What is the inverse Mellin transform of $\Gamma(1+i s)$?
Mathematica and WolframAlpha both indicate
$$
\mathcal{M}_{s}^{-1}\left[\Gamma\left(1 + {\rm i}s\right)\right]\left(x\right) =
-\,{\rm i}
\operatorname{G}_{\,0,1}^{\,1,0}\,\left(x,{\rm i}\,
\left\vert\, 1 \right.\,\right),\quad
\Im\left(s\right) < 1
$$
but the parameters for the Meijer-G function seem to be invalid.


Question: What is the inverse Mellin Transform of $\ \Gamma\left(1 + {\rm i}s\right)$ ?.

